# Is it possible to get lines from Python tracebacks in eggs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, traceback

In [Python Packaging: Hate, hate, hate everywhere](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2012/6/22/hate-hate-hate-everywhere/), Armin says:

> [...] Python tracebacks no longer included the source lines with the traceback. However there was no technical limitation for why it should not be able to show the correct line numbers there. It was just a bug in the Python interpreter.

I'm seeing exactly this issue for eggs in my virtualenv:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/example/venv/current/bin/my_script", line 37, in <module>
    sys.exit(demo.scripts.foo.main())
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/example/demo/scripts/my_script.py", line 90, in main
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/example/demo/lib/bar.py", line 18, in func_x
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/example/demo/lib/bar.py", line 55, in func_y
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Since this is a known bug, are there workarounds? Is there an issue in the Python bug tracker (I can't find one)?

Comment: Is your Python 2.7 the latest patch? I couldn't find anything about this in Python 2.7's release notes, maybe the bug was in distutils.

Comment: I'm on 2.7.3 -- has it been fixed since? I've found [issue 4223](http://bugs.python.org/issue4223) but that was fixed in 2.7.0.

Comment: Do you want a workaround for "normal" stacktraces that just occur, or can you catch & post-process a traceback?

Comment: Preferably for normal stacktraces, but catching and post-processing would certainly help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proof of concept

```
 import os
 import sys
 import traceback
 import linecache


 def recurse(depth=10):
     if depth:
         recurse(depth-1)
     os.path.join(None, None)


 def locate_filename(filename):

     def generate_segments():
         parts = filename.split(os.sep)
         for i in xrange(len(parts) - 1, 0, -1):
             yield os.sep.join(os.path.join(parts[i:]))

     for segment in generate_segments():
         for path in sys.path:
             candidate = os.path.join(path, segment)
             if os.path.exists(candidate):
                 return candidate


 try:
     recurse()
 except:
     _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
     for filename, lineno, functionname, _ in traceback.extract_tb(tb):
         print filename, lineno, functionname
         relocated_filename = locate_filename(filename)
         if relocated_filename:
             print linecache.getline(relocated_filename, lineno)
```